# why isnt mysql SELECT statement working when I use UNION ALL nodejs, mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

when I run this code, the daysFinalarr is showing up as [undefined,undefined, undefined,undefined,......,undefined];
now, I am not sure why this is happening?
Is there something wrong with the mysql statement??
Please advise!!

I just logged rows and it seems that I am only getting back values from the 1st SELECT statement and not getting anything after UNION ALL part of the statement. seems like that's what's going wrong here. so, why isnt the 2nd SELECT statement working? the part after the UNION ALL statement?

```
var rowsNumber;
app.get('/final',function(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT name,designation,salary,wages_rate FROM employee_details UNION ALL SELECT uan,da,days_present,total_wages FROM attendance_details',function(err,rows){
    if(err){
        console.error('MySQL — Error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    }else{
        rowsNumber = rows.length;

    var nameFinal;
    var designationFinal;
    var salaryFinal;
    var wagesrateFinal;
    var uanFinal;
    var daFinal;
    var daysFinal;
    var totalwagesFinal;
    var nameFinalarr = [];
    var designationFinalarr =[];
    var salaryFinalarr = [];
    var wagesrateFinalarr =[];
    var uanFinalarr =[];
    var daFinalarr =[];
    var daysFinalarr = [];
    var totalwagesFinalarr =[];



    for(var i=0;i<rowsNumber;i++){
        nameFinalarr.push(rows[i].name);
        designationFinalarr.push(rows[i].designation);
        salaryFinalarr.push(rows[i].salary);
        wagesrateFinalarr.push(rows[i].wages_rate);
        uanFinalarr.push(rows[i].uan);
        daysFinalarr.push(rows[i].da);
        daysFinalarr.push(rows[i].days_present);
        totalwagesFinalarr.push(rows[i].total_wages);

    }
        console.log('nameFinal is :', nameFinalarr);
        console.log('daysFinalarr is :', daysFinalarr);
    }

    res.render('final',{rows:rowsNumber,name:nameFinal,designation:designationFinal,salary:salaryFinal,wagesrate:wagesrateFinal,uan:uanFinal,da:daFinal,
        days:daysFinal,
        totalwages:totalwagesFinal});
  });

});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `rows[i].days_present` isn't undefined?

Comment: yeah, I am quite sure.
days_present is a column in the database table attendance_details .

why do you think this should be undefined?

Comment: No idea if this applies to `UNION`, but by default, `mysql` disallows multiple statement queries. See [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries).

Comment: oh, but then how come so many sites showing up how to use multiple statements using UNION ALL ?
I can see in the site, they are saying it becomes vulnerable to sql injections and that's why they are disabled , so what's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like all of those values are undefined. Either you're not querying your database correctly (check your SQL statement), or where it's returning `rows`, the JSON schema you're expecting isn't matching up.

First, try logging `rows` to see what you're actually getting back — this should clearly identify whether you have a problem in your SQL query or not.

Next, you can clean up and improve your code quite a bit here:

1. Don't define `rowsNumber` outside of your route; it will get clobbered each time a request hits your server.
2. `nameFinal` is never being set. What does it do?
3. Use `forEach` instead of an iterator to parse your query results:

   ```
   rows.forEach(row) {
       nameFinalarr.push(row.name)
       designationFinalarr.push(row.designation)
       salaryFinalarr.push(row.salary)
       wagesrateFinalarr.push(row.wages_rate)
       uanFinalarr.push(row.uan)
       daysFinalarr.push(row.da)
       daysFinalarr.push(row.days_present)
       totalwagesFinalarr.push(row.total_wages)
   })
   ```
4. If you're trying to create an array list of elements in your database, why are you even querying it like this in the first place? Make the query to your db to directly get lists of elements in an array. If you *really* don't want to do that though, use something like `Array.prototype.map()` or `forEach` to map the results instead of pushing to a bunch of new arrays. For fun, I did this in one line. Probably can be done with `map()` and `reduce()` more cleanly:

   ```
   var o = {}
   rows.forEach(row => Object.keys(row).forEach(key => (o[key] === undefined) ? o[key] = [row[key]] : o[key].push(row[key])))
   ```

Comment: yeah, I'd like to create an array list of elements.
for the nameFinalarr I am getting the values as ['faraz ahmed, 'pintu', 'agraba',.... ]and I am getting other numbers also as the values in this array. dont know why

Comment: I like the forEach idea. thanks for that
yes, you are right about nameFinal not being set.I had first thought of setting nameFinal first and then pushing it into the array, then thought it'd be better to just push the value into the array without having to do this in 2 steps.

Comment: I just logged rows and it seems that I am only getting back values from the 1st part of the statement and not getting anything after UNION ALL part of the statement. seems like that's what's going wrong here. so, why isnt the 2nd select statement not working? the part after the UNION ALL statement?

Answer (score 1):

well, with the hints provided by the previous replies, I have managed to solve this.
it seems that for multiple statements to work I need to put in something like this

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});
```

and then I needed to change the syntax of the statements too.

so, I had to change the sql query from

```
SELECT name,designation,salary,wages_rate FROM employee_details UNION ALL SELECT uan,da,days_present,total_wages FROM attendance_details
```

to  this below:

```
SELECT name,designation,salary,wages_rate FROM employee_details;SELECT uan,da,days_present,total_wages FROM attendance_details;
```

So, it turns out I didnt need to use the UNION ALL after all.

Anyways, problem solved.
I used this page for help - https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#multiple-statement-queries

Comment: Legend, wasn't sure if this was a NodeJS related issue or what. You cleared it right up. Knew I wasn't crazy when my left/right sides were resulting fine haha! Fast search lovely.